# Security.yml is_secure false not working

Tags: php, symfony1

i'm working in a webservice built on top off symfony framework.

Lately i was trying to make curl requests to a module but it gave me 500 error code reply asking for login and password, i looked inside module and it had the *config* folder with the file security.yml with this contents :

```
default:
  is_secure: false
```

What's wrong? why i can't make curl requests to this module?

Comment: A 500 error code is usually an indication of an error, not an authentication request. Can you look into the error logs?

Comment: if it were an error i'd know it, it's an authentication request because i receive the html login form, so trust me, it's not a bad bad request. Anyway, thanks for the hint

Comment: blame on me i was trying to get it working in a url of the type /webservice.php/module/action and it was routed outside the application path like that : /module/action. 
I dunno why does that way, but now i have it working like a charm, tanks everybody, i ll mark solved the first answer i received :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if 'default' is acceptable? Have you tried 'all' instead?

Comment: Changed and nothing has changed, should i do anything else like clear cache?

Comment: Yes, always clear your cache.

However, `sfYamlConfigHandler.class.php` suggests to me that, 'default' shall work too as it will be merged with 'all'. Try to hit on the 'dev' environment and see at which point it resolves the 500.

Answer (score 0):

What about 'on' and 'off'?

Comment: on and off is deprecated in Symfony 1.4